# multithreading and user interface

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, human-computer-interface

Ok, here we go.
 recently I got fond of **HCI** topics on **interface design**.
 I found out that there could be some way to implement a *multithread* interface in case for reducing the delay of system respons.
 Morover. this may also be possible to say that designing a user interface has tight relationship with **STD**.
 therefore, I wonder if there is any method or techniques to find independant part of ,say,a given STD of a UI that can be seen as threads?

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but I am really having trouble reading this, is there any chance you could perhaps split it into paragraphs, expand the acronyms on first usage and go over grammar such as caps after a full stop.

Comment: ok, coming right up with punctuation

Comment: what about now? still ugly?

Comment: No, that is much much better, thank you again. I am doing some reading and will see if I can help, is this c++ related specifically or relatively language agnostic? Specifically STD could stand for several things dependant on language.

Comment: ok. glad you satisfied.

Comment: sorry for my late reply to your comment. didnt read it carefully. well, as STD I mean State transition diagram and as HCI i mean human computer interaction and here, i dont refer to a certain language. just like a flowchart which can be implemented by any language, I think that any STD can be implemented by any kind of language. am I right? so here ,I am wiling to know that if is it possible by looking at a STD we apply some techniques and find out different threads of a UI (which are independent) and then using multithreading to redesign it?

Comment: Thank you for all the clarification, this certainly gets my +1. This seems a really interesting question. I will see if I can help you regarding structures of multi threaded user interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

A multi threaded interface in most cases is not fundamentally different to it's single threaded counterpart. There is still a single thread listening on interface events and it will still run handlers as events happen. However the difference comes down to what is contained in these handlers. A simple single threaded event loop would look as below:

[image: Single threaded UI diagrem]

A multi-threaded UI is a little different but the principal is the same:

[image]

Effectively long processes which are initiated in worker threads which can then report back to them main UI thread so it can report completion.

In relation to a State Transition Diagram, multi-threading complicates things somewhat however there a number of ways to still accomplish this. The first is to simply map each (potential) thread's path separately, this requires decisions for if any threads are finished at the points the main thread checks. It is also possible to use a thread state transition diagram which can demonstrate many threads in a single diagram but is sometimes harder to parse.

Now regarding using a state transition diagram to help implement threading in a user interface program you simply have to locate tasks between the event handler and returning to listening which are time consuming and likely to block. You then need to dispatch these tasks as a thread, optionally adding a completion callback in the main thread.

If I have missed anything please comment below, otherwise I hope this is helpful.

Comment: ok, quite nice answer. but there is still a problem, i would like to know that if the threads are independent? for example, considering a browser that the user looking at a site and browser is downloading a file concurrently. at this point, both actions are independent. but how to see this in a STD? do we need other modelings like MVC?